# Firestore rules: will a general write rule override the more granular update/delete/create rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In the Firestore Security Rules guide it is stated: "A read rule can be broken into get and list, while a write rule can be broken into create, update, and delete".

Then they show this code:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // A read rule can be divided into get and list rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      // Applies to single document read requests
      allow get: if <condition>;

      // Applies to queries and collection read requests
      allow list: if <condition>;
    }

    // A write rule can be divided into create, update, and delete rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      // Applies to writes to nonexistent documents
      allow create: if <condition>;

      // Applies to writes to existing documents
      allow update: if <condition>;

      // Applies to delete operations
      allow delete: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

What happens if you also include an 'allow write' for the cities collection, like so:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // A read rule can be divided into get and list rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      // Applies to single document read requests
      allow get: if <condition>;

      // Applies to queries and collection read requests
      allow list: if <condition>;
    }

    // A write rule can be divided into create, update, and delete rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow write: if <condition>;

      // Applies to writes to nonexistent documents
      allow create: if <condition>;

      // Applies to writes to existing documents
      allow update: if <condition>;

      // Applies to delete operations
      allow delete: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Will the write rule override the other more granular rules?

Thanks.

Link to guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not think of any rules as "overriding" other rules.  The only thing you need to know is this: *if any rule allows access for a read or write operation, then no other rule can later deny that access*.

So, if you have a write rule that allows write access in some situation, it doesn't matter what any other rule says about that situation.

I suggest reading further into that page of documentation that you linked in the section about [overlapping match statements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements).

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't read two paragraphs further for the answer... Thanks Doug.